# Strange Loading Issues in Watchkit iwatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

In iwatch app, my notification is called and I get the updated data in string. In NSLogs I verified, but my iWatch Label is showing the old data only, seems like UI cannot be reload, the text in the label is not set.
Does anyone know this issue and how to fix this, because the updated data is coming but label is not showing updated data.

This is several times that I get the updated data in my method but UI do not get updated.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you set the data to the label. Please show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/) states:

> An interface controller can make changes to its interface only during initialization and when the interface is active. Once the didDeactivate method is called, any attempts to change the value of related interface objects are ignored until the interface controller’s willActivate method is called again.

Try to set the title in `willActivate` using the `setText:` method.